# Deploying multiple Django projects, or apps?

Tags: python, django, nginx

I just got Django installed on my nginx server and deployed a project that exists at the domain's root level: mydoman.com/map. I will be building other Django projects on this server, but they will not share the same database, so they can't be different apps from the same project, right?

Can I set up some level of abstraction between my sites? Like mydomain.com/map/map_index, and mydomain.com/map/admin for the admin side? Then something like mydomain.com/votes/vote_index and mydomain.com/votes/admin for the admin side of that site?

I would want mydomain.com/map and mydomain.com/votes to be two separate projects, using the same Django instance, sharing the same site-packages folder. Both projects will need modules like django-storages and django-memcached.

Answer (score 1):

Mkay. First of, it is possible to build one app [with multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/). Just FYI. But I'd suggest you to use different app. Really.

Yes, you can, easily, because nginx is so easy to use!

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location /one/ {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/run/uwsgi/one.sock;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 60;
    }

    location /two/ {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/run/uwsgi/two.sock;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 60;
    }

    ....
}
```

This confis assumes you are deploying with uwsgi socket-file. So you have one uwsgi-djangoapp instance on /one/ locaton(url) and different on another.

Comment: So would each project be completely contained and all I would have to do is upload each project to the server?

Comment: You should do a bit more steps: upload django app, create database, sync&migrate, create uwsgi configuration file to start it's workers(uwsgi_pass recieves path to worker socket file), collectstatic, restart uwsgi. Also, don't forget to map static to location like /one/static and assume this prefix in your app!